# Append rows with data and after corresponding cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I got stuck for a while trying to expand row numbers in excel using OpenPyxl and xlsxwriter.

Now my file looks like:

[image]

And I need to append another data, corresponding to Shape, and move everything down, so it will look like:

[image]

I have my data ['a', 'b', 'c'] stored as a list. Do I need to use a dictionary instead? Or any easy approach?

For now my code looks like:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
import xlsxwriter
import collections

INPUT_FILE = 'output.xlsx'



wb = load_workbook(filename=INPUT_FILE)
ws = wb['cond']

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


def get_data(start, stop, col):
    mylist = [ws.cell(row=i,column= col).value for i in range(start,stop)]
    findings = [v for i,v in enumerate(mylist) if mylist.index(v) == i]
    return findings

def get_data_row(start, stop, row):
    mylist = [ws.cell(row = row, column = i).value for i in range(start, stop)]
    values = [v for i,v in enumerate(mylist) if mylist.index(v) == i]
    return values

def write_from_dict(row, col, dict):
    row = row
    col = col
    for key in dict.keys():
        worksheet.write(row, col, key)
        for item in dict[key]:
            worksheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
            row += 1



if __name__ == '__main__':

    mammo_findings_list = get_data(2,10, 11)
    us_findings_list = get_data(10, 17, 11)
    mri_findings_list = get_data(17, 27, 11)

    mammo_params_list = [get_data(2, 5, 14), get_data(5,8,14),
                         get_data(8, 9, 14), get_data(9,10, 14)]
    mammo_data = dict(zip(mammo_findings_list,mammo_params_list))


    mammo = write_from_dict(1, 1, mammo_data)


    shape_val = get_data_row(15, 19, 2)
    margin_val = get_data_row(15, 19, 3)
    density_val = get_data_row(15, 19, 4)

    mass_dict = dict(zip(mammo_params_list[0],shape_val,margin_val,density_val]))
    print(mass_dict) 

    test = write_from_dict(1,2,mass_dict) #eventually didn't work for me now

    workbook.close()
```

Dictionary output:

```
{'Shape': ['Oval, Round', None, 'Irregular'], 'Margin': ['Circumscribed', None, 'Obscured, Microlobulated, Indistinct, Spiculated'], 'Density': ['High density', 'Equal density, Low density', None]}
{'Mass': ['Shape', 'Margin', 'Density'], 'Calcifications': ['Typically benign', 'Suspicious morphology', 'Distribution'], 'Assymetry': ['Assymetry'], 'Lymph nodes': ['Lymph nodes']}
```

And I just need to append/merge this data somehow and write everything to Excel simultaneously.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your code look like at the moment?

Comment: @CharlieClark edited post.

Comment: Thanks. Any reason why you're using both libraries? openpyxl should be able to do everything you need.

Comment: @CharlieClark no specific reason, just didn't find everything in openpyxl. I am very new to excel manipulation.

Comment: It looks to me like your functions are trying to be too clever. Could you provide some sample rows / columns in the source workbook and how you expect these to change? Probably makes sense to break the task down into a single part. What's missing in openpyxl?

Comment: @CharlieClark updated post again, that might help you to understand what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154471/discussion-between-charlie-clark-and-alice-jarmusch).

Answer (score 2):

If we restrict ourselves to converting a dictionary of terms to relevant columns in a worksheet.

```
values_dict = {
'Shape': ['Oval, Round', None, 'Irregular'], 
'Margin': ['Circumscribed', None, 'Obscured, Microlobulated, Indistinct, Spiculated'], 
'Density': ['High density', 'Equal density, Low density', None]
}
```

If this is not the case then the lists contained in the strings need expanding first.

The simplest approach is to work with each key, values pair separately. For openpyxl this would be

```
for col, (key, values) in enumerate(values_dict.items(), start=1):
    ws.cell(row=1, column=col, value=key) # column title
    for row, v in enumerate(values, start=2):
        ws.cell(row=2, column=col, value=v) # column values
```

But this involves a lot of row and cell coordinate counting that we try and avoid in openpyxl. An alternative approach is to use `zip` to convert the columns of values to rows that we can add.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
headers = []
values = []
for k, v in values_dict.items():
    headers.append(k)
    values.append(v)
ws.append(headers)
for row in zip_longest(*values):
    ws.append(row)
```

Of course, it would be better still if the intermediate structures could be removed.